# Starburst/Stroke Messing Up on Export

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, export, png, stroke

Having some issues exporting a file in Illustrator. I'm using a dashed stroke for the starburst effect and it gets all weird on me when I export it to pdf.  If I export to png then I'm left with something else.

If I export it to pdf it looks like [this.](https://imgur.com/mpE93Es)

If I export to png it looks like  [this.](https://imgur.com/cFyw7OJ) (which I want it to look like minus the stuff outside the art board.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you expanding the stroke before exporting? No idea what the problem is but I'm sure that would fix it.

Comment: Agree, most likely because it's not expanded. Maybe when it is exported to a png, the artwork is shrunk. You can emulate this kind of scenario, by trying to shrink your artwork and you can see that the strokes increases its widths if not expanded. Maybe the same thing is happening when exporting to png.

Comment: What software are we talking about here?

Comment: Should have mentioned I'm using Illustrator.  Also I'm trying to achieve this as the final result .http://imgur.com/0lGTWnY.  I tried expanding the object and still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up exporting to png and using photoshop to crop the edges if anyone is wondering.